# Update all records of a table according to a view result

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

I have a view like below

```
ITEMNO  INCOME  OUTGO
AA         10     2
BB         15     0
...
so on
```

I'd like to update every record of the ITEMS table (item cards) according to above view's results.

I created a stored procedure like below

```sql
SET TERM ^ ;
ALTER PROCEDURE UPDATEITEMSQTY (
    ACTIVEYEAR VARCHAR(4) )

AS
declare variable ITMNO VARCHAR(20);
declare variable INCOME NUMERIC(18, 2);
declare variable OUTGO NUMERIC(18, 2);

begin 
  FOR SELECT IM.ITEMNO,
             COALESCE(SUM(IM.INCOME),0) INCOME,
             COALESCE(SUM(IM.OUTGO),0) OUTGO
  FROM ITEMMOVEMENTS IM /* View */
  WHERE  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM IM.TDATE )=:ACTIVEYEAR and           
  GROUP BY IM.ITEMNO
  INTO :ITMNO,:INCOME,:OUTGO  
    
  DO
  BEGIN   
    UPDATE ITEMS /* Item Cards Table */
    SET INCOME=:INCOME, OUTGO=:OUTGO,
        STOCK= :INCOME - :OUTGO
    WHERE ITEMNO=:ITMNO;
  END
 SUSPEND;
End
^
SET TERM ; ^
```

Above stored procedure doesn't correctly update **some** records.

Comment: Yes, you posted your query.  So what's your question?

Comment: Even though there is no any movement on *some items* i see Income=3 Outgo = 3

Comment: You should be using [`MERGE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-dml-merge.html) for this, not a stored procedure. In any case, please provide a [mre], which includes DDL of the tables and views involved, sample data (as insert statements), expected results for that sample data and actual results.

Comment: In any case, this could be due to the view. There seem to be some cases where the cursor stability introduced in Firebird 3.0 doesn't work for views, and that means if the view references the table being updated, it might not have a stable result.

Comment: Mark, i didnt know Merge, i learnt it thanks to you  and i solved the problem  Thank You SO SO Much